# WordPress HTML Editor Removing Form Tags

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, strip

My companies wordpress HTML editor is removing html form tags whenever I try to add this search form to the front page via the editor. On my localhost it works fine, but I can't figure out why my companies WordPress is taking it all out.

Here is what I try to add:

```
<div id="bigSearch">
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search By Keyword...." />
<div id="statusInputs">
<select class="status" name="statusOne">
    <option selected="selected">Status</option>
    <option value="foreclosed">Foreclosed</option>
    <option value="Mountain View">Mountain View</option>
    <option value="Golf Course">Golf Course</option>
    <option value="High Speed Access">High Speed Access</option>
    <option value="Basement">Basement</option>
    <option value="Club House">Club House</option>
    <option value="Elevator Access">Elevator Access</option>
</select>
<select class="status" name="statusTwo">
    <option selected="selected">Status</option>
    <option value="foreclosed">Foreclosed</option>
    <option value="Mountain View">Mountain View</option>
    <option value="Golf Course">Golf Course</option>
    <option value="High Speed Access">High Speed Access</option>
    <option value="Basement">Basement</option>
    <option value="Club House">Club House</option>
    <option value="Elevator Access">Elevator Access</option>
</select>
<select class="status" name="statusThree">
    <option selected="selected">Status</option>
    <option value="foreclosed">Foreclosed</option>
    <option value="Mountain View">Mountain View</option>
    <option value="Golf Course">Golf Course</option>
    <option value="High Speed Access">High Speed Access</option>
    <option value="Basement">Basement</option>
    <option value="Club House">Club House</option>
    <option value="Elevator Access">Elevator Access</option>
</select>
<select class="status" name="statusFour">
    <option selected="selected">Status</option>
    <option value="foreclosed">Foreclosed</option>
    <option value="Mountain View">Mountain View</option>
    <option value="Golf Course">Golf Course</option>
    <option value="High Speed Access">High Speed Access</option>
    <option value="Basement">Basement</option>
    <option value="Club House">Club House</option>
    <option value="Elevator Access">Elevator Access</option>
</select>
<select class="status" name="statusFive">
    <option selected="selected">Status</option>
    <option value="foreclosed">Foreclosed</option>
    <option value="Mountain View">Mountain View</option>
    <option value="Golf Course">Golf Course</option>
    <option value="High Speed Access">High Speed Access</option>
    <option value="Basement">Basement</option>
    <option value="Club House">Club House</option>
    <option value="Elevator Access">Elevator Access</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Search" />
</form>
<p id="advanced"><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is what it spits out on my companies WordPress

```
<div id="bigSearch">
<form action="#" method="post">

<div id="statusInputs">

Status
Foreclosed
Mountain View
Golf Course
High Speed Access
Basement
Club House
Elevator Access


Status
Foreclosed
Mountain View
Golf Course
High Speed Access
Basement
Club House
Elevator Access


Status
Foreclosed
Mountain View
Golf Course
High Speed Access
Basement
Club House
Elevator Access


Status
Foreclosed
Mountain View
Golf Course
High Speed Access
Basement
Club House
Elevator Access


Status
Foreclosed
Mountain View
Golf Course
High Speed Access
Basement
Club House
Elevator Access

</div>

</form>
<p id="advanced"><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions while I try to figure it out would be much appreciated...

Comment: some plugin maybe? Or maybe the editor strips out certain tags be default. You can use a plugin that allows you to insert html through shortcodes

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee any plug-ins you know of from experience that do so? I e-mailed our server/wordpress handler who does all the backend of it, so maybe he knows of a plug-in that is messing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this plugin to insert html as shortcodes

You would create a shortcode corresponding to search form. And insert it into your post

http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/

Comment: Thanks, of course my server guy doesn't give me permission to add plug-ins via WordPress OR FTP... Seriously? Thanks though. If I don't get a fix from some one else that isn't a plug in i'll mark yours right when I can add this darn thing.

Comment: oh. I suggest bugging the server guy for a fix until he gives u admin rights  :)

Comment: You would think they would give the lead designer access to his work right? Nope. Guess not, haha, they don't trust an 18-year to know what he is doing I guess.

Comment: :headdesk: :headdesk: :headdesk: Wordpress development in a nutshell: "I have problem A". "Simple, use plugin A". "I have problem B". "Simple, use plugin B". "I have problem C". "Simple, use plugin C". "I have problem D. "Simple, use plugin D". "I have problem E". "Well, of course you do. Look how many plugins you're using!"