# Wordpress Text Block deletes form inputs

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to edit a Wordpress website adding a form. I'm adding this form into a text block writing it in pure html. The thing is when I go to the preview Wordpress deleted the input tags.

I tried looking for someone with the same problem, but I haven't found nothing yet.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code I'm adding into the textblock. The input tags disappear.

Thanks!

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://test.cl/bridge.php">

<table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%; text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        User:
      </td>
      <td style="width:70%; text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;"> 
        <input name="nombre" type="text" id="inputNombre" placeholder="User" style="width:90%">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:30%; text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        Password:
      </td>
      <td style="width:70%; text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        <input name="pass" type="password" id="inputPass" placeholder="Password" style="width:90%">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        &nbsp;<br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" style="border: none !important; width:170px; padding:4px ; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; background-color: #0CF; color:#069; border-radius:20px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        &nbsp;<br />
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center; border: 0px solid #ffffff;">
        <a href="http://test.cl/index.php">
          Forgot your password?
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by WordPress is deleting your input tags.  I copied and pasted the code you posted into a WP text editor (using the text tab, not the visual tab) and then was able to preview the page which displayed the form.  https://imagebin.ca/v/4EZzILO9aTSK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress HTML Editor Removing Form Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758061/wordpress-html-editor-removing-form-tags)

Comment: Is it the only way using a plugin?